# Invalid state parameter in Jmeter

Tags: jmeter, google-oauth, state, google-api-python-client

I am implementing load testing in Jmeter for my web application which uses **google oauth**. 
I have generated access token and refresh token and passed it to my HTTP request, but the request fails with an **Invalid state parameter**.
I checked various posts on passing a random string of 30 characters but the value is not being recognised. 
I am not sure how to use the google API library for python to generate one as there is only snippet available in the official site and am quite unsure if that value will be recognised.
Any suggestions on how to achieve my usecase?

Answer (score 0):

We are not telepathic enough to guess how exactly you "generated" the tokens and how they're "passed to your HTTP request"

My expectation is that you need to pass only one token: the "access" one "to your HTTP Request", refresh token can be exchanged for the new access token when the previous one expires. Passing 2 tokens doesn't make sense and may cause the problem you're facing.

As per the [main page of JMeter project](https://jmeter.apache.org/)

> The Apache JMeter™ application is open source software, a **100% pure Java application** designed to load test functional behavior and measure performance. It was originally designed for testing Web Applications but has since expanded to other test functions.

hence you cannot use Python libraries directly in JMeter, either look for a Java library, I think [this one](https://github.com/googleapis/google-auth-library-java) is a good choice and use it from [JSR223 Test Elements](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#jsr223)

If you still want (or have to) use Python - you can run Python scripts from JMeter using [OS Process Sampler](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-run-external-commands-and-programs-locally-and-remotely-jmeter)

Comment: I meant the same as you mentioned, I passed the access token to 'HTTP request' and exchanged it for refresh tokens when the previous one expires.
I was passing only one token to the HTTP request. However, it pops with 'Invalid state parameter' message.

Comment: I couldn't be successful in generating state parameter with python libraries. I shall try with java. Thank you!